# Unexpected starting index in double for loop

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, indexing, range

I am trying to construct a for loop wherein I will use the indexes of the loop to be the elements in my list. Here is my code:

```
a1 = []
a2 = []
for i in range(1, 91, 2):
    for j in range(1, i, 2):
        a1.append(float(i))
        a2.append(float(j))
```

Ideally, I would like `a1` to start with `1.0`, but when I print its elements, I get that it starts from 3.0 instead:

```
[3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0...]
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am really confused. I thought I will have `1.0` as the first element first followed by `3.0`, thanks to the step of 2, and so forth.

As I wasn't able to find any answers about this, I apologize if this has been asked before. Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: Thanks everyone for your input on what was happening! You all were very helpful.
And thanks jojo for correcting my format.

Comment: In your inner loop, if `i=1` you have `for j in range(1,1,2)` which is an empty list. Whatever is in the inner for loop is not executed in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when `i = 1` the inner `j` loop has the form:

```
for j in range(1, 1, 2):
   ...
```

And therefore runs no iterations as the `range` function returns an empty list.

```
>>> range(1, 1, 2)
[]
```

Therefore no *appends* are performed in the first iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when i is 1, the inner j loop never happens. So what you want to do is append i to a1 before you go into the inner j loop

```
    for i in range(1, 91, 2):
       a1.append(float(i))
       for j in range(1, i, 2):
           a2.append(float(j))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that this produces a different output, as `i` will only be appended once per iteration of the outer loop, so, for example, `5.0` will only be once in `a1` and not twice as in the output shown in the question.